# Tandem/twin circuit breakers installed where not allowed?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I decided to read the panel's diagram today and IF I understand it correctly, you can only use tandem/twin breakers in designated slots.  Referring to the diagram, it looks to me like circuits 11-17 on left can use them, but 1-7 can't.  However, if you look at the picture of the box's breakers, you'll see there are twins where they shouldn't be, like circuits 1 & 3.

Am I reading this correctly?  If not, could someone please set me straight?  If I *am* reading this correctly, then how "bad" is it?  Even though I plan to get an electrician's recommendation on replacing the panel (because it appears they no longer make those breakers), I want to know.  Perhaps it affects the load balance on the neutral vs hots?  (It seems odd to me they didn't key them so you couldn't use one where it wasn't allowed).

I'm adding a hi-res pics of the panel & some of the spare breaker.
Thanks,

Jim

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The alien breaker I think you're referring to the breaker with the red switch.  The home inspector found a double tapped breaker & I wanted that fixed before the sale.  My guess is since they don't make the original GE breakers anymore, he found one that fit (it's a Bryant).  There is a spare breaker sitting on top of the box (GE type TR) & it's a twin breaker that looks like the ones in the box, but I didn't pull the cover off to verify those breakers are the same ones.

Comment: It's an urban myth that all 1" breakers are interchangeable. They do snap in, but the bus clips don't mate correctly, and they arc-fault and melt the buses. I see at least 4 styles of breaker, so I'm betting one is alien.  Yeah, the BR caught my eye, but it might possibly be the CL type, which is UL-classified for this panel.  If you want any more analysis on alien breakers, I need a much higher rez photo because the text on the breakers matters. Otherwise I can understand if  you'd rather take the advice of the guy you met *and paid* rather than some Internet nobody.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to know your endgame goals: are you selling it and don't care?  Selling it and want it to be right?  Or buying it and want it to not go ka-floof when you load it in ways the previous owner did not?

Comment: Just so you know, I'm not asking for suggestions on what to do about this--I just want to know what the ramifications are with this issue (what problems could it cause).  But, to answer your question...I bought the house a couple of years ago.  The circuit breakers are old and I think should be replaced (I'm concerned about false trippings).  Rather than try to find equivalent breakers, I'm seriously considering having the entire panel box replaced.  I want to know how bad this is to help determine the priority of fixing this (the house has lots of issues that I've been taking care of).

Comment: While the panel is painfully small for a house, it has free spaces, so clearly works.  I quite agree, all the breakers look old and replacement would be wise, *and certainly moots the alien breaker issue*.  But I wouldn't throw out the panel with the bathwater. Buses don't wear out, it's just a matter of finding a breaker whose clip is rated for that bus stab.  I'm trying to prime the pump for the experts, who may say "current GE breakers work" or "Eaton CL is UL classified for this panel" (don't quote me on that), then you just saved a grand.

Comment: (I deleted my earlier comment about keying because its' better described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_total_limitation).

Comment: @AdirondackJim -- can you get us a better photo of the panel itself please?  I suspect you have alien-breaker problems atop the misplaced double-stuff

Comment: Sure.  Are you asking for a closeup of the breakers?  Also, does anyone know the answer to my question:  what's bad about putting the twin breakers in a slot that isn't supposed to accept them?

Comment: Harper--100 amps is fine for me--especially once I replace the electric range with gas (should happen in about a week).  As for replacing only the breakers, it looks like there's enough circuits for putting twin breakers only where they belong. 
 However, there's sooo much (mis)information out there about using other manufacturer's breakers, I'm not sure how "kosher" it is.  I'd have to discuss that option with the electrician.

Comment: Harper--I didn't see the earlier posting about more information on alien breakers.  If you think there could be a serious issue, then sure, I'll get you more pics.  Just let me know what you need (like take the cover off).  But, I'm not really keen on removing the breakers to get a pic of the sides (but I can send a pic of side of the spare one).

Comment: I don't disagree with anything said. Would add that installation and labeling instructions are submitted with the product for lab (UL) testing. We don't always know what criteria the engineers were trying to satisfy when they submitted those documents, and can it be unwise to second guess them.

Comment: @AdirondackJim -- closeups are nice, but we'll need a set of them...a single photo can do the trick, as long as it shows the whole panel clearly enough that one can read the writing off the breakers

Comment: @AdirondackJim -- the issue with double-stuffs in slots not designed for them is that that can lead to a panel that's overstuffed, which then leads to heat issues (why UL came up with Circuit Total Limiting in the first place)

Comment: I'm uploading more pics right after this comment, including some of the spare breaker.  ThanksThreePhase-- I think you're referring to heat inside the panel.  But I still don't fully understand though:  the total current is limited by the main breaker and the panel should be able to handle 100A (and the associated heat it generates).  As for the CTL (thanks for link), then shouldn't the breakers be keyed so you can't overload the panel?  I'm assuming maybe they should've been and people suspect the ones that are in there are from a different manufacturer that happen to fit the non twin slots.

Comment: @AdirondackJim -- is the existing panel surface-mounted to an unfinished wall, or flush-mounted into a finished wall surface?  Also, how tall is this breaker box (in inches)?

Comment: The panel is mounted on plywood attached to an unfinished wall.  It's 21 x 12.5 inches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The existing tandems are of the correct model for this panel...

Your existing panel appears to be a *very* old GE panel, of a style that predates the current THQP half-width GE breaker, as well as the formal introduction of Circuit Total Limiting panels.  These ancient panels use type TR tandem breakers instead, and the spare breaker you photographed indeed is a type TR, in addition to looking identical from the face.

### ...but are indeed misplaced

This means that while the panel labeling only permits tandems in certain slots, neither the breakers nor the panel are keyed to enforce that, and thus you can get your current situation, where the installer slapped tandem breakers in wherever convenient.  This, while not an issue at the moment, can lead to problems with heat down the road if more tandems get shoved in there, stuffing the panel beyond its 20-circuit limit.  This is possible if 240V or multi-wire branch circuits are present, as those mean that the number of neutrals will not match the number of hots, rendering the 20-hole limit on the neutral bar irrelevant.

### A millstone about your neck, if ye wish to keep it

Furthermore, the age of this panel means that it is one of the few cases where new production breakers of the labeled type are *not* compatible with the panel's busbar system. In other words, if you bought new-make GE THQL breakers for this panel, expecting them to fit and work, you'll be in for a major disappointment, as they likely *won't even fit*, as per [this DIYChatroom post](https://www.diychatroom.com/f18/old-ge-tql-breakers-short-circuit-current-218842/index2/#post1543809) (pertinent parts quoted below for posterity):

> GE changed the way they set the breaker's seating height. In my panel, you push the breaker down until the top of the molded slot rests on the stab. TQL breakers, THQL Issue UOxxx (probably MJxxx, NExxx and others too), and also Siemens QP and Eaton BR, can work this way, because they all have the same slot profile.
>
> Recent panels have a ridge of insulating material next to the stab; the bottom of the breaker's case rests on the ridge. The stab is not as tall. It doesn't penetrate the breaker as deep. All the above breakers (except TQL which somehow doesn't quite fit) can be mounted. Also Issue RT-xxx of THQL, which doesn't fit the old bus because it can't accommodate the tall stab. Issue RT-xxx is all you will find in retail stock.

This means that your breaker selection is limited to NOS (new old stock) THQL breakers of Issues that *will* fit the panel, which is a dicey source of breakers at best, or to Eaton CL breakers that have been UL *classified* for use in GE panels (among others).  However, while the latter can be obtained reliably from any electrical supply house that deals in Eaton products, the UL classification process limits you to a small subset of possibilities.  Namely, using CL breakers limits you to a maximum of 50A branch circuits, and means you can't get double-stuff breakers, two-pole arc or ground-fault breakers, dual-function (arc fault/ground fault) breakers, or other exotica for your panel, either.

Nonetheless, if you wish to keep this panel, you can, provided it is in good condition on the inside still.  You'll have to rearrange this panel so that the double-stuff breakers are in slots designated for them, though, and replace that BR120 that currently sits in the bottom left with an Eaton CL120.  Note that you'll want to keep the spare TR breaker if you do this, too, as they are *extremely* difficult to find nowadays, since they have not been made in roughly half a century or so.

### Replacement options

If you do decide to blow the money and replace this panel, you have a couple of options.  First, you could replace the whole panel with a 100A, 24-space or 30-space, main breaker panel.  This gives you a brand new panel, of a manufacturer of your choice, and plenty of room for future expansion as well.  Note that you'll have to replace the breakers wholesale to go with this panel swap, which may mean you have to put AFCIs in.

The other option would be to use a *retrofit interior kit* (mostly an Eaton thing, although Siemens now offers a retrofit interior as well) to replace the existing bus structure in the panel.  This would also require a wholesale breaker replacement, and requires costlier parts than replacing the panel outright, but has the advantage that the existing enclosure (cabinet) can be left in place.  This is useful if removing the old cabinet is impractical, something that is often the case for flush-mounted panels, or if rigid conduits come into the panel from both sides or the top and bottom.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm guessing the panel is the original (house was built in mid 60s).  If I want to replace all the breakers with new ones (which means no twins), I'll be short on slots.  But, I could live with one or two twin breakers (and keep all the old ones as spares).  Something to think about.  An interior retrofit won't solve this either.  So, it's either replace breakers or panel.

Comment: How do you know the Bryant type BR isn't valid and the Eaton CL is?  Is there a chart somewhere that shows equivalent breakers?  I'm asking because I was hoping to install a 220V 15 or 20 amp breaker before I have an electrician replace the breakers/panel (it's for a table saw that I want to hook up soon).  I would need to get the appropriate type.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the retrofit interior kit.  Maybe it would allow newer twin breakers, so it could be an option.  If so, I'll need to discuss that with the electrician.  Thanks.

Comment: @AdirondackJim -- because your panel isn't *labeled* to take type BR breakers, but type CL breakers are UL *classified* to work with GE panels.  A CL215 or 220 will do the trick for your tablesaw.  And yes, the retrofit kits will work with appropriately typed double-stuff breakers.

Answer (score -2):

Shared neutrals are not allowed per NEC Code . Piggy back breaks with shared neutrals are phasing two circuits on one neutral conductor. Example is look at a piggy back breaker using a shared neutral conductor the discoloring of brown or black of the insulated neutral where conductor is terminated.

Comment: MWBCs are still permitted under the NEC (and still useful in some niche cases).  You are correct that the hot legs of a MWBC are required to be on opposite phases, but it's not at all clear from your post where the querent even has such an issue...