# Upgrade 100A panel to use more solar

Tags: electrical-panel, solar

My question is:  Is it reasonable to upgrade to a 200A main panel but with a 125A breaker?

Here is a draft of my thinking based on feedback so far:

1. Upgrade my main panel with 125A service over existing SDGE wiring.
2. Replace existing 1975-era panel with a 200A panel with 125A Breaker (e.g. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-200-Amp-20-Space-40-Circuit-Outdoor-Ring-Type-Overhead-Underground-Main-Breaker-CSED-with-Kit-SC2040M200C/202495825 looks like it fits, keeping top breakers less than 6’7”.  It would be about 8” taller but same width as current panel.
3. Upgrade wiring to garage panel to 100A
4. Install new solar array with Enphase microinverters which feed into my garage sub panel.

Does this make sense?

[image: Photo of existing panel label]

[image: Draft of new design]

Comment: Does your solar tie in at the main panel or at the subpanel?

Comment: Also, can you post photos of the labeling on the inside of your main panel's door please?

Comment: The Solar Edge inverter feeds into the bottom of the main panel, at the other end from the main breaker.

Comment: Are there any other breakers besides the solar feed and the subpanel feed in the meter main?

Comment: Is there any other labeling than that?  That looks like it's more about the overall assembly (meter+main+panel) and I'd expect a great deal more detail on other topics such as accessory part numbers,torque settings, and many other things including bus ampacity and upgrade instructions.  The labeling is sometimes behind the panel deadfront, if you're comfortable taking that off.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- older panel labels tend to be somewhat sparser than their newer counterparts

Comment: The house has grown and been remodeled over the years (this panel was probably installed in 1975).  Beyond the 70A sub panel and the 20A solar feed, most of the circuits are lighting and room outlets.  All of the kitchen, HVAC, EV charging, etc is on the sub panel.  I’ll post a photo of my thinking in the main post.   Thanks all for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

To me a "200A panel with 125A main breaker" means a panel with bus bars that are rated for 200A minimum, but breakered so the utility service is limited to 125A. I see nothing wrong with that, but there are others on DIY more qualified than I who will be able to explore the nuance of having PV sources also feeding the panel. It may be that the 200A+ bus bars allow you to have that 125A main breaker plus something like 70A of PV fed into the panel through a backfed branch breaker as well. (I'm not certain.)

One thing I can tell you is that there are time-tested, but not widely-known, underground construction methods for upgrading that service conduit without trenching. (Directional drilling is but one method, but I'm not suggesting it because it's very expensive to mobilize for such a small job as this).

Look into pipe splitting or bursting. These pass a tool through an existing pipe of clay, ductile iron, steel, or plastic and break it apart, compacting the surrounding soils and making room for a *larger* pipe to replace the original. A plumber who does sewer line replacement may be able to do this for you or refer you to a contractor who can. Pricing varies regionally and over time of course, but there's a fair chance you could get the conduit upgrade done with lower cost or pain than you had anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't make this harder than it is!

The #1 blunder in this area is ***assuming*** "100A main panel".  Yes, I know you think it's that, but look closer.  Dollars to donuts **it's *actually* a 125A panel** with a 100A main breaker. Check your panel labeling.

Which is a game-changer for solar; here's why.

You know a little about "the 20% rule".  The reason for the rule is that if you had 100A utility and 100A of solar, then on a sunny day your loads could collectively pull 200A and no breaker would trip.  This needs to be prevented.

Since solar comes into the panel *on the opposite end of the bus*, * a 20% bus overload is considered acceptable. Hence the 120% rule. **But this applies to the panel bus, not the main breaker**.

Enter the design habits of manufacturer in the 70s.  100A was a common service size, but so was 125A.  Panel manufacturers don't like unnecessary SKUs and do like selling upgrade kits. So most of them only had one bus design of 125A -- and they sold it with a 100A breaker, and offered a 125A upgrade kit for people with actual 125A services.  So most "100A" panels are in fact 125A bus. Check your panel label to be sure - I bet it specifies a compatible 125A breaker.

*Wow, that's a game-changer for solar*.

120% of 125A is 150A, leaving you 50A headroom for solar.  **No upgrade needed** (probably).

"That was easy"

---

I boggle at how many unnecessary panel upgrades are done because solar installers *just miss that*.

### Get on the bus

* By the way, did you catch the part about solar feeding *from the opposite end of the bus*?  I'm sure you've done that properly inside the subpanel.  But did you do it in the main panel?  In this case that means the subpanel breaker must be on the opposite end of the bus from the main breaker, since solar originates from it.

*Now that I've made vividly clear* that "bus rating" and "main breaker rating" are not the same thing, and the only requirement is that bus rating >= main breaker rating, let's talk about your actual question.

> Is it reasonable to upgrade to a 200A main panel but with a 125A breaker?

Yup. It's reasonable to have a 100A main breaker with a 125A bus rating, since they sold 50 million of them.  That works because 100 <= 125.

So yeah, 125A breaker on a 200/225A bussed panel works too, since 125 <= 200 and 125 <= 225.

Yeah, "200A" panels are sometimes 225A-bussed.

Those people telling you otherwise just have their little comfort zone, are afraid of their boss, and don't want to think too much. I would not allow them to have any further input into your electrical design.

> I’m also curious about what is grandfathered in with the upgrade. For example, my garage subpanel is on a 3 wire circuit. Would upgrading the main panel require retiring the subpanel as well?

That's grandfathered still. But you really ought to fix it.  It was outlawed for a reason.

Realistically, the way the industry is changing, panel/service upgrades may become a thing of the past. Smart panels/breakers are now a thing - they report circuit current to the main computer, and can switch on/off by computer command. This allows dynamic load shedding, which reduces the need for service upgrades. This technology also enables ["next-gen" demand-side management](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f9GpMWdvWI), so I expect it will take off fast. Expect this in the next 5-10 years tops.  If you can make it that far with the panel you have, you may never need a service upgrade.

Comment: I edited my reply to show the label on the door of the panel, which looks to me like it is restricted to 100A

Comment: @Luna if that's all the labeling there is, then regrettably there is nothing to indicate 125A busing (but I'd feel better if you peeked inside).  However, that panel is *very* obsolescent and breakers are a problem, so most likely the solar people are planning to illegally use a HOM, BR or MP/QP breaker.  So it's a dead-end, that happens with "combo panels".  Get a meter-main and separate panel - panel tech is moving very fast with "smart panels" and load side management, and expect to replace it again in 10-15 years.

Answer (score 1):

### You'll want to replace that meter-main *anyway*

While that meter-main is currently limiting your solar production as it only has a 100A bus on it, that's not the largest issue with that piece of hardware.  No, its more pressing problem is that you'll have trouble getting breakers that fit properly in it, as GE gear that old has [trouble accepting new-production THQL breakers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/183856/tandem-twin-circuit-breakers-installed-where-not-allowed/183874#183874) due to subtle changes to the breaker design.

As a result, I'd recommend straight-up swapping it for something that has a 125A bus on it, so that you can have the wiggle room to add all the solar capacity you're looking to add at your main panel, and upgrade the feeder to the existing subpanel to 100A if you so choose.  Given that your utility (SDGE) is an EUSERC member utility, that you need a 125A bus with a 100A main breaker to deal with the amount of solar you are planning to have, and that your existing meter-main is a *semi-flush* mount unit (recessed into the wall instead of being surface mounted), the Eaton MBE1224PV100BTF is your best bet here.

Note that most "smart panel" hardware out there is designed for 200A services, so you'd probably need to take the hit on a service upgrade anyway if you went that route.

### Don't feed solar in at the subpanel

The other thing I'd recommend is rearranging your setup to feed all the solar in at the main panel.  This avoids a recursive set of NEC 705.12 busbar loading calculations, replacing them with a single application of the rule, and generally keeps complexity down.  (If you need to use an AC combiner panel to bring the SolarEdge system and the Enphase microinverters together, that's fine as you can do that with a "spa panel" sized subpanel.)

Answer (score -1):

Two main choices to consider:

1. Upgrade your main panel and incoming service line.
2. Add battery storage to smooth out the peaks.

Both will be expensive. Personally I'd opt for #2 because you'll have protection from power outages.

Edit: misread the part about SDGE's 20% rule, thought it was related to NEC 80% continuous. That caps the feedback power at 16.7A.

Battery storage allows you to increase your solar generation by time-shifting its output. It eliminates the need to modify the main panel or any existing wiring. The additional solar + battery attaches to the 200A sub-panel which has plenty of capacity for up to 16.7A of battery + solar power. See diagram:

[image]
The battery buffers peak excess power, feeding at most 16.7A into the sub-panel and therefore to the main panel if no loads are on the sub. It stores up excess energy during the day and feeds it back for consumption day & night.

Using smart breakers that communicate with the battery, you could add up to 16.7A of additional "smart" load. 70A from the grid, 16.7A from the battery. The smart breakers would shut off as the battery depletes.

This assumes routing the existing solar to the battery to maximize energy to the battery.

Alternatively, if the battery sat between the main panel and sub-panel, it could feed back up to 16.7A to the grid while sending up to 70A to the sub-panel. I'm not sure if such a controller exists.

Comment: Check out the SPAN Panel. It's pricey, but the reviews say it does a good job. https://www.span.io/