# GE Panel Tandem In Wrong Place

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

A relative just moved into an apartment. I am a little unsure about the small, old GE panel:

[image: Panel Image]

with this information page:

[image: Panel Information]

**Space 1 has a tandem 20A breaker.**

As I understand it, the top row (1,2,3/4, 5/6) is not supposed to have any tandem breakers, but the bottom row (7/8, 9/10, 11/12, 13/14). Obviously with just a single tandem pair, there isn't an overload issue, but it still appears to be *wrong* to put a tandem in 1, 2, 3/4 or 5/6. A little confusing actually for 3/4 and 5/6, but maybe the same front cover was used for some other panels that allowed tandems in 3/4 and 5/6, or maybe I am just confused about the diagram and 3/4 and 5/6 actually *can* have tandems. And staring at it a little more, I think I finally understand the left vs. right diagram - the difference is whether 1 & 2 are a main breaker or not - simply depends on whether the hot feed wires go to a main breaker and middle lugs used for a subfeed vs. hot feed wires to the lugs and everything just branch circuits.

1. How serious a problem is the tandem in space 1? My hunch is that it has been this way for a very long time, and I am a little leery of becoming the "problem tenant's problem relative". But if this is a real problem and not just "GE limited the *total number* of tandems to avoid certain types of problems" then it is a different story.
2. The breakers look like three groups: (a) 1, (b) 2, 3/4, 7/8, 9/10, 11/12, 13/14, (c) 5/6. Do those all look like valid GE or legitimately listed alternatives?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Interesting possibility. I'm not eager to pull off the deadfront from a rental panel... And I knew you were not the downvoter!

Comment: If the cover were upside down, the reset/tripped wording would be upside down, too.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I agree. But some panels are designed to mount either way. But it really wouldn't make much sense here as this is pretty clearly set up in "all branch breakers" mode, not "main breaker" mode, so the feed goes to the middle of the panel. The time to flip a panel is typically to run the feed up into the bottom to a main breaker instead of having to loop it through the whole panel to get to the top. But stranger things have happened.

Comment: Can you explain what you're seeing in the diagram that says there should be no tandems on the top row? I'm not doubting you, I just don't know what to look for.

Comment: As a member of the "main breaker on the bottom" club (but I had to point out to my licensed electrician installing the panel that putting it on top was going to be stupid and annoying and I didn't want that, whatever his knee-jerk inclination might have been) I concur. @FreeMan note the "split into two lines" .vs. "single line" for the breaker spaces on the diagram. 7-14 are allowed to be tandems, while even though the cover says 3-4 and 5-6 there's only one line to those.

Comment: Ah, got it, @Ecnerwal, thanks. It's even more clear from the labeling stamped on the panel. Spaces 1 & 2 are full-size spaces, each with a single slot number while the rest are a pair of numbers for a single full-size slot. That, though, lead to the confusion about putting tandems in 3/4 and 5/6 which is clarified by the label inside.

Comment: @manassehkatz excellent, not messing with a rental.  I didn't even know my winter cottage had 120V/30A service for 15 years, (let alone that it shared this with Air Conditioner Lady) ... we just never had a reason to look. *It never gave us problems*.  Still amazes me how little power a house needs.

Comment: @ecnerwal *precisely why* the cover might be upside down. Most panels have 2 legal orientations, but you're clearly intended to orient *this cover* one way.  Now the question is: is it rotationally symmetrical?

Comment: I see three possible scenarios: 1 - Panel *is* upside down, cover was flipped accordingly, tandem in the right place, latest fix (breaker swap or whatever) and cover was put back right-side up because why shouldn't it be right-side up. 2 - Panel has illegal and *bad* tandem in the wrong place. 3 - Panel has illegal but "nothing really wrong" tandem.

Comment: Does the apartment have any 240V loads?  Breakers 11/12 and 13/14 appear to be handle-tied, which should make it easy to figure out if it is a main and the cover is upside down, or if the panel is lug-fed and thus the cover is right-side up and the tandem is in the wrong place.

Comment: FWIW - my last house had that exact same panel and I don't remember if it was possible to mount the cover both ways or not - it has been too long and I deleted all the photos of it once I wouldn't need to work on it anymore.  I had to open it to replace the Eaton BR AFCIs the last owner installed and replace them with CL.

Comment: No 240 loads. Dryer is 120. I assume water heater and furnace are gas as oven is gas. I can't imagine the handle tied pair is main as it is only 20a.

Comment: Yeah, 20A main does seem pretty low, even for a tenant panel.  I've seen tenant panels with 30A mains, though --  In coastal CA where all the big loads are gas and they have no A/C because of the mild climate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yeah, this tandem doesn't belong there

Considering that from the logo being on top we can assume that the loadcenter is mounted right-side-up, and that the intended space numbering is stamped on the cover as well, the tandem/double-stuff TR breaker in space 1 is in a space that is not intended to hold tandem breakers.  Switching it with the T(H)QL breaker below it in spaces 7/8 will correct this problem for now, but this panel will need to be replaced if you want anything more done with it since it [doesn't support current production THQL or THQP breakers.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/183856/tandem-twin-circuit-breakers-installed-where-not-allowed/183874#183874)  (As an aside, UL *classified* Eaton CL breakers *would* work with your panel, but there are no Classified double-stuff breakers out there, so it doesn't solve the problem of that ancient TR double-stuff being unobtanium/a barrier to additional functionality.)

Answer (score 1):

First, I would look to see if this is the first means of disconnect. Is there a Main breaker outside at the meter? If not, I would install one at 1 & 2. Make sure it is wired for that inside the panel. Otherwise you have more than the maximum six ways to turn everything off as per the NEC.
Norm McDonald

Comment: I *hope* there is disconnect at meter, but no way to tell as it is a rental (and in addition, I am not the tenant). My hunch is there are a bunch of meters for the building all together in a mechanical room, but whether each has a disconnect, I have no way to know. If it ever came to installing a disconnect here, I don't think reconfiguring this panel as backfed main (though it *can* be configured that way) would be practical - it would be time for a modern, larger, panel.

Answer (score -1):

This could be a multi wire branch circuit. This practice is generally frowned upon, although it was often used in commercial environments.

When a MWBC is present, both will need to trip together to be safe. That might be why its a tandem, but you'll need to trace the wire.

Comment: "This practice is generally frowned upon" [citation needed]. Unless you're putting a *FCI breaker on which are _very_ expensive, there's nothing at all wrong with MWBCs.

Comment: If MWBC hots do not trip together, they are quite unsafe and that is certainly problematic.

Comment: That doesn't mention the issue of neutral overloading, but I don't think that's typically a big issue in residential split phase.